# javascript recursion to find children by array position

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a bunch of tasks and I need to find all children based on the task I click.  I would like an array of position [ 1,2, 3] to come back so I can work with those rows.

Here is an example.

```
    var taskAR = [
    {
        "isParent": true,
        "parentID": null,
        "level": 0
    },
    {
        "isParent": true,
        "parentID": 0,
        "level": 1
    },
    {
        "isParent": true,
        "parentID": 1,
        "level": 2
    },
    {
        "isParent": false,
        "parentID": 2,
        "level": 3
    },
    {
        "isParent": false,
        "parentID": 2,
        "level": 3
    },
    {
        "isParent": false,
        "parentID": null,
        "level": 0
    },
    {
        "isParent": true,
        "parentID": null,
        "level": 0
    },
    {
        "isParent": false,
        "parentID": 7,
        "level": 1
    }

];


function getNestedChildren(arr, parentID) {
    var out = []
    for (var x = 0, len = arr.length; x < len ; x++) {
        var d = arr[x];

        if (d.parentID == parentID) {
            var children = getNestedChildren(arr, x);

            if (children.length) {
                d.parentID = x;
            }
            out.push(x)
        }
    }
    return out
    }

   getNestedChildren(this.master.tasks, parentID)
```

thanks for the help

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: And, do you have the ability to change the structure of your data?  There are MUCH better ways to represent parent-cheild relationships than what you are using/

Comment: Yep I can change it if there is a better way.  The idea is to find all the children of the parent and then work with them both from the found array and on the display.

Comment: the problem I think is here:              if (children.length) {
                d.parentID = x;
            }   do I need to put another loop in there to get the position??

Comment: BTW, a nice way to organize parent-child relations can be seen in DOM: a binary tree with left branch pointing to a firstChild and right branch pointing to a nextSibling. It might be augumented with the idea of skip list to eliminate the need of flattening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with this code: First is that you are not accumulating values.  You need the output from the nested call to `getNestedChildren` to be returned in your `out` array.  Second, I don't know why you are changing any `parentID`s when this runs, it should be a read-only operation.

Take out

```
        if (children.length) {
            d.parentID = x;
        }
```

and replace it with

```
        out = out.concat(children);
```